# Javascript Geolocation for Mobiles

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm doing a page that will record the location of the device, using [HTML Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp). My point is to post the last coordinates in a WebService and store it in somewhere.

I tried it in my Android phone using Firefox Mobile, them it works fine, except that the browser needs to be the active at the moment. My next step is to find a way to make that page running in background. It’s possible? There is another way to reach my point?
It must to be only JavaScript and HTML, avoiding things like Appcelerator.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZXwu/2/)

```
­
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have mobile web browser if you only want JavaScript & HTML. However, you can't always have it running in background.

You should write a native mobile app for this purpose which allow to access location service while running in background with the permission of users.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the exact code and text of the "geolocation error"?

At present you cannot get coordinates if browser window is inactive or browser is in background or mobile itself in sleep mode, unless you are developing a hybrid App with something like phonegap/cordova. (Firefox has the exception of continuing to service watchPosition() *if* the App is foregrounded but the phone is asleep.)

I have made several suggestions to W3C, IETF, Chrome Dev, Mozilla Dev, and Edge Dev regarding a workable solution using the [Service Worker Extensibility](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#extensibility) functionality for a Javascript-only solution.

Briefly, the UA tracks Geolocation changes and if within range of a dev supplied filter, a ServiceWorker will be instantiated which may foreground the App or merely notify the App Server.

*Please* pursue this issue with the relevant bodies as the idea is beginning to gain traction.

HTH